# How can I find the Monday in the current week in node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have below code to get the current Monday based on the given date parameter. It works fine for most of time. But it doesn't work when it cross year. For example, if I pass `new Date('2020-01-02T15:33:50Z')` as the parameter, it returns `2019-12-29T15:33:50.000Z` which is not correct. It should return `2019-12-30`. How can I make it work for cross year case?

```
function getMonday(d) {
  d = new Date(d);
  var day = d.getDay(),
      diff = d.getDate() - day + (day == 0 ? -6:1); // adjust when day is sunday
  return new Date(d.setDate(diff));
}
```

Comment: The test works for me, it gets me `2019-12-30`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My idea in this regard is that if there is such a problem with cross years, then you can try to start from the raw format in which the date is presented, namely the number of milliseconds since 1970, and operate with this number to find Monday. For example like this:

`let currentDate = new Date();` get current date

`let currentDateMs = currentDate.getTime();` get current date in milliseconds

`let dayNumber = (currentDate.getDay() + 6) % 7;` in Date object the countdown of days in the week starts from Sunday, so we shift it so that it starts from Monday

`let result = currentDateMs - 86400000 * dayNumber;` subtract the number of milliseconds in a day (1000 * 3600 * 24 = 86400000) multiplied by the number of the current day (0-6) from the current date, and also because of this, we do not need to check if it is Monday, since the Monday number here is 0 and this will eliminate unnecessary subtraction

`let resultDate = new Date(result);`

`console.log(resultDate.toDateString());`

Answer (score 1):

You can change all the dates to timestamps and then subtract the difference.

```js
function getMonday(d) {
  const value = new Date(d)
  const value_seconds = value.getTime() / 1000
  const value_day = value.getDay()
  
  let diff_seconds = 0 // default, expect value_day is monday

  if(value_day > 1){ // if day is tuesday to saturday
    const diff_day = value_day - 1
    diff_seconds = diff_day * 24 * 3600 // find different in seconds
  }
  if(value_day === 0){ // if days is sunday
    const diff_day = 6 // substract by 6 days, back to monday
    diff_seconds = diff_day * 24 * 3600 // find different in seconds
  }

  const result_second = value_seconds - diff_seconds
  const result = result_second * 1000

  return new Date(result);
}

const today = new Date()
console.log(getMonday(today))
console.log(getMonday(today).getDay())

const issuedDate = new Date('2020-01-02T15:33:50Z')
console.log(getMonday(issuedDate))
console.log(getMonday(issuedDate).getDay())
```